# Running a bash script after some containers are initialized

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I'm planning to run a *.sh* script after some containers are up to make some REST requests.

Created a job to wait for these initial containers, filled `initContainers` tag in *.yaml*.

First, i thought creating a container with using a Linux distro as a base image. Then it didn't seem quite right.

Isn't that waste of resources ? What is the best practice for this situation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WIthout knowing what you are aiming for and how you are testing you deployment, it's going to be difficult to give an anwser. Are the REST request part of the configuration of your container? Why create a job waiting for the initial container? You say you filled something in the yaml, a bit of code could help. Without context it's going to be hard to say you are waisting resources or not

Comment: @night-gold It's completely irrelevant. Long story short, i need to wait until 2 containers are up and running, and then make a rest request to somewhere else. Creating a job was the best option i could find. Would be happy to get different ideas about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any kind of image as base image. The only resource you're consuming (not wasting) is disk space.

Kubernetes will pull the image and that will consume disk space on the node. As soon as the init container has done it's work, it will be stopped and won't use any more RAM or CPU which are the real precious resources in the cloud or on bare metal.

If you're worried about the image size, you can also try to use the same image as the user container (the main container) but starting a different command from it.

This will make the node just pull on image and no additional space appart from your script will be consumed.

Another option could be to use a very small distro like alpine.

If you can write your initialization routine in go you can also use your go binary as image like discribed [here](https://medium.com/@chemidy/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324).

Comment: One extra question - Does Kubernetes wait until the initContainers are started - or finished ?

Comment: Init containers offer a mechanism to block or delay app container startup until a set of preconditions are met. Once preconditions are met, all of the app containers in a Pod can start in parallel.

See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#examples) some examples.